# Number of lanes/classification of road at a desired direction or bearing

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am using OSmnx to explore street network orientation. I can see I can get street bearings that are the number of roads at a particular bearing through OSmnx. Is there also a way to determine the number of lanes of those roads at that particular bearing? or maybe the classifications of roads?

Comment: Both are available as edge attributes, when present on OSM. The latter is the `highway` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

First, `map = ox.graph_from_place('Paradise, California')` then `nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(map)` then `nodes.head()`. Source:https://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/